# Fade out a modal box after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [remodal](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#readme) for the contact form on my website.

I'd like the modal box to close-out automatically after 1 or 2 seconds once the form is successfully sent.

The line used to close the modal box on success is inst.close();

I've tried this inst.close().FadeOut(3000); but that didn't work.

Thanks for your help

Code of my contact form:

```
// Contact Form
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactfrm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var inst = $.remodal.lookup[$('[data-remodal-id=modal]').data('remodal')]; // this was added by me
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

        function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };
        if (isValidEmail(email) && (message.length > 1) && (name.length > 1)) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sendmessage.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
                    $('.error').hide()
                    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                    inst.close(); // this was added by me
                }
            });

        } else {
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Just to be clear you mean  `inst.close().fadeOut(3000);` .. not  `inst.close().FadeOut(3000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to work with callback functions:

```
$('.success').fadeIn(1000, function() {
    inst.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        this.close();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I add this just after? $('.success').fadeIn(1000);

Comment: I've just edit my answer. Hope this is what you need